# (ASP.NET MVC) Files Served in the Browser Have No Extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, mime-types

I have the following code that serves the file to the user in the browser. The served file has no extension, and the users have to add the extension manually in order to open it.

```
public ActionResult OpenDoc(int id = 0)
{
    Document doc = dbContext.Documents.Single(d => d.DocID == id);

    byte[] data = (byte[])doc.Data;
    string mimeType = doc.MimeType;
    return File(data, mimeType, doc.DocName);
}
```

When I debug, I see that the mimeType is "application/pdf" which is correct. However, the file is being served without the pdf extension. Why is that and how can I correct it? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

```
return File(data, mimeType);
```

This won't suggest a file name for the saved file and the browser will suggest one based on the URI along with mapping `application/pdf` to `.pdf`.

Or:

```
return File(data, mimeType, doc.DocName + ".pdf");
```

Which will add `".pdf"` to the file name suggested.

Of course, if there are multiple mimetypes in `dbContext.Documents` then you'll need to have some way of knowing what extension to use in a given case. The easiest way is probably to save the extension upon the file initially being added:

```
return File(data, mimeType, doc.DocName + "." + doc.Extension);
```

Alternatively you can have a lookup of supported filetypes, or just include the extension in `DocName` to begin with.